# Safe to say Disjunction (OR) is considered as Logical True while Conjunction (AND) is considered as Logical False

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm back again to ask some discrete mathematics question. I was studying about the connectives with truth table while i stumbled upon a similar case. I wonder if i'm right to safely assume that

```
Disjunction (OR) is considered as Logical True while Conjunction (AND) is considered as Logical False
```

As we all can see from the links i given below, it contains the truth table

[Logical Conjuction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_conjunction)

From what i observed from this Logical Conjuction(AND), whenever there is a FALSE is any of the column of the logical conjuction, i can safely deduce that the end result is a false. For instance if it's a T and T, then it must be T. If it's T and F or F and T or even F and F then it must be false.

[Logical Disjunction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_disjunction)

Similarly, if a column of logical disjunction contains T then the end result must be T.

Hence is it right to say that Logical Disjunction is Logical True while Conjunction is Logically False.

Regards.

Comment: You can have both be false.  For example: $P(x)=\begin{cases}\text{true when}~x~\text{is even}\\ \text{false otherwise}\end{cases}$ and $Q(x)=\begin{cases}\text{true when}~x=5\\ \text{false otherwise}\end{cases}$.  You have $P(1)\vee Q(1)$ is false as well as $P(1)\wedge Q(1)$ is false.  If your claim was that $(P\wedge Q=\text{false})\Rightarrow (P\vee Q=\text{true})$, then that is disproven by the counterexample above.

Comment: yeah, that's true. maybe using the term logical true and logical false ain't correct. But for this case, it is safe to assume that whenever a logical conjunction column has a false, the end results will be a false while a logical disjunction column has a true, the end results will always be a true? Accordingly to the truth table, it seems to be the case. As for now, I'm still learning the basics of connectives and it seems like you're putting 2 condition under a variable which could be why my initial understanding is being disproved by your example.

Comment: If at least one of the columns is false, then $P\wedge Q\wedge R\wedge \dots$ is also false.  If at least one of the columns is true then $P\vee Q\vee R\vee \dots$ is true.

Comment: so simply saying like mention above, as long as under the logical conjunction truth table's column has a false, i can safely assume it's a false while logical disjunction truth table's column has a true, i can also assume it's a true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "considered as Logical True". However, the notion that:

> If a column of logical conjunction contains F, then the result must be F.
>
> If a column of logical disjunction contains T, then the result must be T.

is definitely correct. Indeed, [the Domination Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_equivalence#Logical_equivalences) state that for any proposition $p$, we have:

> $$p \land F \equiv F$$
>   $$p \lor T \equiv T$$

Comment: ah i see. thanks. i guess i must have mixed up the domination laws with the "logical true/false" understanding. But am i right to say that, with just this domination law, i can almost use it to prove every other single law that is in logical equivalence, for etc Identity laws and Idempotent laws.